# Navigating back to different page (UWP, Template 10)

Tags: c#, uwp, template10

I need to ignore a page while navigating back, I tried the following:

```
public override async Task OnNavigatingFromAsync(NavigatingEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
    {
        args.Cancel = true;
        NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    } else { 
        args.Cancel = false;
    }
    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

On the page that I am navigating away from, but it seems to only cancel the navigation.

What is the best way to tackle this issue?

Comment: Because you're settings `args.Cancel = true;`. This means that you want to cancel navigation

Comment: If I don't cancel it will simply keep navigating back, to the previous, unwanted page.

Comment: I don't get your point, you're saying "but it seems to only cancel the navigation". So what you want to do then? Explain it in more detailed way.

Comment: First sentence. I want a different page when a "back" navigation happens.

Comment: So just change `typeof(MainPage)` to another type and remove `args.Cancel = true;`. This should navigate "back" to specified page. (If I understood correctly)

Comment: This specific navigationservice (template 10) requires the type of page you want to navigate to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the page that you want to ignore, you can add the following method. This will allow to remove the current page from the navigation history.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // here NavigationService is supposed to be an instance of Template10 INavigationService
    var backStack = NavigationService.FrameFacade.BackStack;
    if (backStack.Count > 0 && backStack.Last().SourcePageType == this.GetType())
    {
        backStack.Remove(backStack.Last());
    }

    base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
}
```